# Maven giving compilation error : With package does not exist for the referenced jars

Tags: maven, compilation

I am trying to create a new maven build project and create jar from it. The project compiles for simple code but when I use some of the filenet jars it below below errors on compile and install maven commands :

My POM looks like this. I have not done anything apart from just building a maven project project, used jars in build path and created a class. It was Please let me know if I can provide any more details for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.are</groupId>
  <artifactId>aredemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\ARE\works`enter code here`pace\aredemo\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target</directory>
    <finalName>aredemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>D:\ARE\workspace\aredemo\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>


Error coming on maven build and compile commands :

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/ARE/workspace/aredemo/src/main/java/com/are/eventaction/DocumentSecurityUpdateEventAction.java:[3,30] package com.filenet.api.engine does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/ARE/workspace/aredemo/src/main/java/com/are/eventaction/DocumentSecurityUpdateEventAction.java:[4,30] package com.filenet.api.events does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/ARE/workspace/aredemo/src/main/java/com/are/eventaction/DocumentSecurityUpdateEventAction.java:[5,33] package com.filenet.api.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/ARE/workspace/aredemo/src/main/java/com/are/eventaction/DocumentSecurityUpdateEventAction.java:[6,28] package com.filenet.api.util does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/ARE/workspace/aredemo/src/main/java/com/are/eventaction/DocumentSecurityUpdateEventAction.java:[8,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class EventActionHandler


Looks like some configuration or version issue but couldn't figure it out
```

Comment: You need to add the dependencies you are using to the pom file...

Comment: Thanks for response @khmarbaise I am not using any dependencies. I am just using some ibm jars files by configuring them in the build path. Do I still need to any them somewhere in the POM

Comment: What do you mean by `..some ibm jars files by configuring them in the build path` ? Please show an example.